# Laravel 8 || Hostgator

Tags: laravel, servidor, dominio, laravel-8

Buen día, estoy trabajando en mi portafolio en el servicio de dominio hostgator (no usa control de versiones), tengo una aplicacion web, aclaro que en mi localhost funciona todo al 100. Adjunté mi aplicación en una carpeta del servidor, la conecté a la base de datos, etc.

Al entrar por la url parkinglot.fabianromero.net me recupera los datos con éxito pero al intentar realizar un post me sale el siguiente error.

Me hes extraño porque en mi localhost funciona todo bien. La comunicación con la base de datos funciona porque me trae todo el GET, al añadir un dato es el problema, adjunto imagenes del error.

[image: Mensaje que devuelve el servidor]

De ésta manera se encuentra mi modelo:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function typeCar()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\TypeCar');
    }   
}
```

Así importo los modelos en el controlador:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
//models
use App\models\Car;
```

Así se encuentra la funcion mi controlador

```
public function addCar($idType, Request $request){
    try{
        $flag;
        $msg;

        $car = new Car();
        $car->driver = $request->nameDriver;
        $car->type_id = $idType;
        $car->save();
        $car->refresh();

        $flag = 1;
        $msg = "The vehicle was successfully created.";

    }catch(Exception $e){
        $flag = 3;
        $msg = "Error when adding vehicle. Please try again";
    }
    return response($this->notificationCar($flag, $msg));    
}
```

Uso comunicacion AJAX

```
 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"addCar/" + $('#selectTypeCar').val(),
        data: obj,
        success:function(data){
            contentNotification(data.status, data.titulo, data.message);
        }
    });
```

Mi ruta:

```
Route::post('/addCar/{idType}', [CarController::class, 'addCar'])->name('addCar');
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, recalco hostgator no usa control de versiones.

Comment: El código y mensaje de error van como texto

Comment: Ahora lo corrijo.

Comment: Si estás usando la estructura de carpetas que da Laravel entonces tú error es muy simple, la carpeta models debe llevar la M en mayúscula y al tratarse de eso quedará cerrada

Comment: No según tu código lo escribiste con mayúscula, ahora te pasa por alto en local esto por que no todos los so son estrictos en ese sentido entonces insisto, escribe el nombre con M mayúscula

Comment: Disculpa, TIENES TODA LA RAZÓN, ya funciona. Muchisimas gracias!!! (Sin querer elimine mi comentario anterior)